# How can I manually update pip on all pyenv virtualenvs?

Tags: pip, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I use a different virtual environment for every project I work on (using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#simple-python-version-management-pyenv) and [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#pyenv-virtualenv)), and I often come across a message like then when installing a python package using `pip`:

> ```
> WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/.../.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/envs/sdge/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> ```

However, when I run the `pip install --upgrade pip` command, it only upgrades pip in that particular virtual environment (which is expected, and that is behavior that I want), and it is annoying to see this across all my different virtual environments.

Is there some kind of shortcut (either with `pyenv`, `pip`, or the shell) that I could use to run `pip install --upgrade pip` on *every* virtual environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use `pyenv` so I created this code after reading documentation and source code (not tested):

```
for env in $(pyenv virtualenvs --bare --skip-aliases); do
    pyenv activate $env
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pyenv deactivate
done
```

Comment: Works for me. I added the `--quiet` flag to the `pip install` command, but that's just my personal preference.